# How to create model with foreign key in slick?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, slick

JVM requires case class of model with foreign key to be:

```
case class Customer(id: Option[Int], name: String, surname: Option[String], gender: Option[String], addressId: Int)
```

And in this case instead of address object it will be only id in json.

To generate JSON with internal address object it should be like:

```
case class Customer(id: Option[Int], name: String, surname: Option[String], gender: Option[String], address: Address)
```

And in this case code does not compile. How should class Cusomers look like to make it work properly?

```
class Customers(tag: Tag) extends Table[Customer](tag, "customer"){
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def surname = column[String]("surname")
    def gender = column[String]("gender")
    def addressId = column[Int]("address_id")
    def * = (id.?, name, surname.?, gender.?, addressId) <> ((Customer.apply _).tupled, Customer.unapply)
    def address = foreignKey("address",addressId,addresses)(_.id)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Slick, your table class should represent your sql table, so I would keep the `Customers` class as you wrote it. 
In my `DAO`, I would have a method:

```scala
def findCustomersWithAddress(): List[(Customer, Address)] = {
    for {
       customer <- customers
       address <- adresses if customer.addressId = address.id
    } yield (customer -> adress)
}.list
```

To generate JSON, you can write a `json.Writes[(Customer, Address)]` or a method:

```
def toJson(customer: Customer, address: Address): JsObject = Json.obj(
  ...,
  "address" -> Json.toJson(address)
)
```